# Find the points surrounding a point in a 2D space

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of points in a 2D space: the blue one (which contains hundreds of points) and the red one (which contains hundreds of thousands of points).

For each blue point I have to find the three closest red points that surround it given their coordinates, as shown in the figure.

[image]

Which is the most computationally efficient algorithm to do it?

Comment: Instead of the top one, why not the one to the right and slightly below? You'll have to answer this question in order to create an algorithm. What you could do is to scan the points in order of their distance to form a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `scipy.KDTree` for one set. Then use `query` with the second set.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query

EDIT: This does not guarantee that the found points surround the queried point but it gives you good candidates. At this point you can brute-force the check whether the three points surround the queried point and retry with more neighbors if they don't.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice solution. However, the Brute forcing part seems quite inefficient and the risk is of invalidating the advantages, in terms of speed, of the KNN algorithm. I would like to know if there exists some heuristic that can be applied instead of the brute force.

Comment: @Francesco Brute-forcing for a small set of points may be a reasonable choice, especially in Python where any sophisticated algorithm probably has too many small steps that cause too much interpreter overhead. The best optimization that I can think of is taking two points and then figuring out where a third point would need to be for it to create a triangle surrounding the search point. But that doesn't change much about the big-O complexity, especially in the worst case.

Comment: @Francesco Another idea would be to compute the minimum convex polygon using N nearest neighbours. Grow the point set exponentially until the search point is inside the polygon. Then remove points starting with the points farthest away (maybe by bisecting the neighborhood size) until you find one "critical" point that has to be part of the polygon. Keep this point and continue removing the remaining points until you find a second, then the third. This leaves you with the triangle you are searching.